# equivalent of python's array.pop() in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, selection-sort

I wonder if there's an easy to implement equivalent to python's `array.pop()` which returns the deleted element while deleting it from the array in parallel in javascript.

```
let nums = [2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6];

function sortArray(nums) {
  let arr = new Array();
  let smallest_index;
  for (let j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
    smallest_index = find_smallest(nums);
    console.log("smallest", smallest_index);
    arr.push(nums.splice(smallest_index, 1).join(""));
  }

  return arr;
}

function find_smallest(arr) {
  let smallest = arr[0];
  let smallest_index = 0;

  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < smallest) {
      //   console.log("this");
      smallest = arr[i];
      smallest_index = i;
    }
  }
  return smallest_index;
}
```

it seems that if I replace javascript's (`nums.splice(smallest_index, 1).join())` with python's `(arr.append(nums.pop(smallest_index))` I would get a perfectly sorted array. is there a similar straightforward solution in javascript as well ?

Comment: Have you tried the JavaScript `.pop()` method?

Comment: javascript `.pop()` method deletes the last element of the array so therefore, we have no control of actually selecting it by passing an index @Pointy

Comment: Oh, OK. Well, it shouldn't be called `.pop()` in Python then.

Comment: yes, it's only misleading if we're cross-working with python and javascript

Comment: It's not misleading at all.  It is presumptious of you to assume that the libraries in two entirely unrelated languages should be forced to work exactly the same.

Comment: I'm confused, doesn't Perl, JavaScript, Ruby and Python all have the same "remove last element and return it"  `pop`?

Comment: Is this for education purpose or you are trying sort the array? If the later then, `array.sort()` would a simpler and faster solution...

Comment: "Pop" in computer science generally refers to the [operation that is performed on a stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)). Of course people will assume that a pop method on a collection will remove the last element.

Comment: @vanowm i'm going through the book called grokking algorithms by Aditya Y. Bhargava, so it's for educational purposes as i'm trying to learn how to implement selection sort and how exactly does it work under the hood :) \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you use splice. Here's an example of the implementation below:

```js
Array.prototype.pythonPop = function (index) {
    return this.splice(index, 1)[0];
}
```

Now, I found the issue, you'll *love* the answer. So you were using `num.length` but your methods were augmenting the length of `num` array. Which is why your answer had only half the needed numbers. See code below. I cached the `length` prop of `nums` array

```js
let nums = [2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6];

function sortArray(nums) {
  let arr = new Array();
  let smallest_index;
  console.log(nums)
  for (let j = 0, length = nums.length; j < length; j++) {
    smallest_index = find_smallest(nums);
    console.log("smallest", smallest_index);
    console.log(nums)
    arr[j] = nums.splice(smallest_index, 1).join("");
  }

  return arr;
}

function find_smallest(arr) {
  let smallest = arr[0];
  let smallest_index = 0;

  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < smallest) {
      //   console.log("this");
      smallest = arr[i];
      smallest_index = i;
    }
  }
  return smallest_index;
}

console.log(sortArray(nums))
```

Comment: umm....How is this any different than what they have now? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @vanowm when you use `pop()` in js it removes and returns the last element in the array. But Python's version takes in one param, an index, from which we'll return the value from. So Python let's you pick where to pop from, js just pops the last element.

Comment: But I just realized that my code is missing one small something.

Comment: @KitangaNday i'm afraid this answer doesn't produce any different output than current implementation - output = `[1,2,3]` expected = `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

Comment: @ExodusReed This method implements python's version of Pop method as explained [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/pop). That's what the question is about right. "equivalent of python's array.pop() in javascript"

Comment: that's correct, but it is still unclear for me of why the code would produce the expected output on python but not on javascript even with our `pythonPop()`

Comment: @ExodusReed Yes, I'm actually answering a question you previously wrote, where you used `arr.push("5")` and it didn't work. That's where I was helping you, but as for this question, I've answered the problem. I don't know why it's giving that issue, but will get into it now, since it looks like you were able to bypass your previous hurdle

Comment: yes, indeed, i have bypassed the previous hurdle. thanks for helping @KitangaNday

Comment: @ExodusReed Don't thank me yet, this has been a night of strange bugs, let's resolve this first then see. You can share any attempts here.

Comment: @ExodusReed I've found the issue, can't believe that the answer was staring at me in the face the whole time. You only needed to store the original length of `nums` array -_-

Comment: yeah exactly, we seem to have figured it out at the same time! *lightbulbcrash* haha. i'm gonna try it now

Comment: @ExodusReed _cool_, please if this was the answer you were looking, marking it as the correct answer would be much appreciated.